# Rate Distortion with Squared Error Metric General Formula

Tags: proof-verification, information-theory

I have found a "result" that I am somewhat skeptical about. Could someone please check whether the following arguments are sound:

**Claim:** For any source $X$ with variance $\sigma^2$ the rate distortion function with respect to the squared error metric $E[(\hat{X} - X)^2]$ is given by

\begin{equation}
  R(D) =
  \begin{cases}
    0 & \text{, if } D > \sigma^2 \\
    h(X) - \frac{1}{2} \log(2 \pi e D) & \text{, else}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

**Proof:** The first case if obvious; for $D > \sigma^2$ it suffices to select $\hat{X} = E[X]$. For the second, consider choosing $\hat{X} = X + Z$ where $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0, D)$. We can then see that the lower bound on the rate distortion function (for a squared error measure) given by $h(X) - \frac{1}{2} \log(2 \pi e D)$ [1] is indeed achieved:

\begin{align}
  I(X,\hat{X}) &= h(X) - h(X \mid \hat{X}) \\
               &= h(X) - h(X \mid X + Z) \\
               &= h(X) - h(X + Z - Z \mid X + Z) \\
               &= h(X) - h(-Z) \\
               &= h(X) - h(Z) \\
               &= h(X) - \frac{1}{2} \log(2 \pi e D)
\end{align}

[1]: Elements of Information Theory, 2nd Edition, Chapter 10, Exercise 8

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, the error is obvious:

\begin{equation}
  h(-Z \mid X + Z) \neq h(-Z)
\end{equation}

Clarification: This disproves step 3 -> 4 in the equality chain in the question: $h(X + Z - Z \mid X + Z) = h(-Z \mid X + Z) \neq h(-Z)$.